# Trying to make a shape, never used curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I’m trying to make the shape shown in the picture. I want it to be like a pipe but with this form with closed ends where the arrows are pointing. I’d appreciate any help, I’ve never actually made custom shapes before[image]

Comment: u can create a cube, press m in edit mode, click at center, add a skin modifier, a subdivision modifier, and extrude it till it looks good :D

Comment: You could try using metaballs

Comment: Is this what you're aiming for? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GFip.png

Comment: @HISEROD yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for, would you be able to advise how I'd go about making that?

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, to model this shape, let's start with the large curved section since it is super easy.

1. Add a Bezier curve by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and selecting *Curve* → *Bezier.*
2. Adjust the curve's *Depth* to add some thickness.
   [image: Depth]
3. Set the *Resolution* to a manageable amount. I'll use a *Resolution* of 2 which yields 8 sides.
   [image: Resolution]
4. Adjust the shape to your liking.
5. Set *Resolution Preview U* to a suitable amount for modeling. I used 20.
   [image: Res]
   [image: 4]

### Modeling

1. For this part, the curve must be converted into a mesh. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Convert to Mesh.*
2. In edit mode, find the place that the connecting segment should be. Select the top vertex and the one directly below it and snap the cursor to them using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
   [image]
3. Duplicate either one and move it to either side (just so that it can be seen more easily).
   [image]
4. Use the *Spin* tool to spin the vertex around the x axis. Use the same number of steps as the curve has (in my case 8).
   [image: spin]
5. Select the entire circle with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and make it a separate object by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> and selecting *Selection.*
6. In face select mode (<kbd>3</kbd>), select the outside faces of the tube shape and hide them (hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> to select multiple loops of faces and press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them).
   [image: hid]
7. In side view, go to the *Mesh* menu and click *Knife Project.* Press <kbd>f9</kbd> and click *Cut Through.*
   [image: cut through]
8. Delete the faces on the inside of the cut on each side and merge any problem vertices to ensure that the perimeter of the cut has 8 sides.
   [image]
9. In edge select mode, select both loops, press <kbd>W</kbd>, and select *Bridge Edge Loops.*
   [image: bridged edge loops]
10. If you need extra high quality, you can add support loops and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth out the transition. If you want it to be extra perfect you can get rid of the triangle as well, but I'm too lazy for that.
    [image]

### Tada!

[image]